# Linq2Sql select records by multiple ids?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

For example, I have table with 10000000 records and list **in memory** with 100000 ids.

How I can select all records by these ids?
Obviously, I can do it like this:

```
var ids = GetIds();
var result = from q in ctx.Records
             where ids.Contains(q.Id)
             select q;
```

But if I do it like this, it will have two problems:

- Monstrosity in generated SQL each time I use this query.
- O(N) complexety for each row. So, I will receive my result in couple of years.

How I can do this? How is this done with `linq2sql` or is this impossible to bypass?

---

**Update**

- GetIds - this function returns about 100.000 ids. And no, I can't **join** it. **It is calculated**.
- Yes, I tested it, I debugged it and HAVE seen what is generated. It is something like this:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM Records WHERE id IN (/*one hundreds of thousand goes here O_O*/)
  ```

  Simple math: 10.000.000 x 100.000 will give 1.000.000.000.000 in time complexity. This is extremely unefficient.

Comment: What makes you think it is O(N) for each row?

Comment: what is `GetIds`? Where does that come from and what is the return type?

Comment: Have you tested that it's slow? It will be translated to a `WHERE ID IN(1,2,3,4,5,...,100000)` query. Of course that's not the best way(therefore you could use a  user defined table type and a table-valued parameter but no LINQ-To-SQL anymore).

Comment: Stuff the `GetIds()` in a temp table (or indeed, table-valued parameter as @Tim suggests) and join or query against that.

Comment: @eocron06 - where does `GetIds`get those IDs from?

Comment: If you use a HashSet<T> to store the in-memory list your .Contains would have a complexity O(1) since HashSets are much more efficient in determining if a value exists in the set. Would that serve your purpose?

Comment: Nope, it still will be loaded into in(...) clause. Don't forget what this query launched in DataBase, with it's own syntax, not on your computer.

Comment: I **seriously** recommend a 2-step operation, the first step being to load the 100,000 ids into a temp table in SQL, and the second one being to execute a join-query against said temp table. If you do it any other way, you're not letting SQL Server play to its strengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said doing these operations in memory isn't good. The solution is to have another table in your database and then your code will be:

```
var ids = GetIds();
//Insert all ids into database (bulk insert)

var result = from q in ctx.Records
             join i in ctx.Ids on q.Id equals i.Id
             select q;
```

This way the operation will take place in the database and you will overcome the restriction of the amount of items in a `in` clause.

1. The `id` field of `Records` should have an index (or if it is a primary key it already is also indexed)
2. The id field of your new `Ids` table should also be indexed

This way the join will be a `Hash join` and not a `Nested Join` - equivalent for a .Net solution of using the `ids` collection as a `HashSet<string>` instead of a `List<string>`.

Last, to support many operations in parallel you can have your `Ids` with 2 columns: `Id`, `OperationId`. The `OperationId` will be given to all the `Id`s of a specific insert and then your query would look like:

```
var result = from q in ctx.Records
             join i in ctx.Ids on q.Id equals i.Id
             where i.OperationId = _the operationId given by the insert_
             select q;
```

_Make sure that the `OperationId` is indexed too - can be the same index of the `Id` but see that it is the first in order.

---

Depending on the DBMS you can also have your table as a `temporary table` - where at least for Oracle it stored the data per connected session - so you can insert from multiple sessions at once but the data isn't shared - so you don't need the `OperationId`